# Sums are independent of index

Tags: real-analysis

This may sound like a very stupid question but hear me out.

I was reading analysis from Amann and stumbled upon this remark on page 42:

"Sums and products are independent of the choice of index. That is"

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k = \sum_{j=0}^{n} x_j$$ and $$\prod_{k=0}^{n} x_k = \prod_{j=0}^{n} x_j$$

To be clear, this is how they defined sums and products rigorously in Amann on page 41.

If we have an associative operation $$\cdot$$, they define a function $$V_n: X^n \rightarrow X$$ by $$(y_0, \cdots, y_{n-1}) \mapsto y_{n-1} \cdot x_n$$ and then, form the unique function $$\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$$ such that $$f(n) = V_n(f(0), \cdots, f(n-1)) = f(n-1) \cdot x_n$$
Then, they set $$f(n) = \cdot_{k=0}^{n} x_k = f(n)$$
To get the sums and products, just replace $\cdot$ with $\sum$ and $\prod$ respectively.

Of course, this makes sense intuitively but to prove this rigorously is different. Are sums and products independent of the choice of the index because there is no mention of $k$ or $j$ in this recursive definition? I just want to make sure I make no blanket assumptions before continuing and want to make sure that my understanding of this is completely sound and rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, whatever variable you choose as the index should be a "new" variable. We say that the index variable is not a *free variable* but is *bound*.

Outside of the scope of the sum or product, the variable should have no meaning. Otherwise you start getting conflicting values and all meaning is lost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!